# How to make maven search for artifacts in local repository

Tags: maven

I have a project that worked fine on another pc. And now i'm trying to run it on another pc. There is no acces to proxy. And after any action it says that

> couldn't transfer artifact. no route to host

But i have all depandencies in local repository, maven just doesn't want to take it from there. Is there a way to make him take all artifacts from local repo first?

Comment: You can use `offline` mode, if you have all the dependencies in your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a version difference in the artifacts you have in your local repository and the ones mentioned in pom.xml
Your error : couldn't transfer artifact. no route to host
is because you have'nt added proxy to your pom. eg  :

```
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
     -->
      <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>yourpassword</password>
      <host>yourhost@host.com</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>    

  </proxies>
```

Add it to the settings.xml file in conf folder of maven and try again